# How to scrape the next pages (link)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

We have now the first page of the website [www.theft-alerts.com](http://www.theft-alerts.com) by this code:

```
connection = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.theft-alerts.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(connection.read().replace("<br>","\n"), "html.parser")

theftalerts = []
for sp in soup.select("table div.itemspacingmodified"):
    for wd in sp.select("div.itemindentmodified"):
        text = wd.text
        if not text.startswith("Images :"):
            print(text)
```

Output of the first page:

```
STOLEN : A LARGE TAYLORS OF LOUGHBOROUGH BELL
Stolen from Bromyard on 7 August 2014
Item : The bell has a diameter of 37 1/2" is approx 3' tall weighs just shy of half a ton and was made by Taylor's of Loughborough in 1902. It is stamped with the numbers 232 and 11.

The bell had come from Co-operative Wholesale Society's Crumpsall Biscuit Works in Manchester.
Any info to : PC 2361. Tel 0300 333 3000
Messages : Send a message
Crime Ref : 22EJ / 50213D-14

No of items stolen : 1

Location : UK > Hereford & Worcs
Category : Shop, Pub, Church, Telephone Boxes & Bygones
ID : 84377
User : 1 ; Antique/Reclamation/Salvage Trade ;  (Administrator)
Date Created : 11 Aug 2014 15:27:57
Date Modified : 11 Aug 2014 15:37:21;
```

On the website are more pages (1 to 19). We only see page 1. How can we get the rest of the pages?

We tried this:

```
connection = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.theft-alerts.com', 'http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-2.html', 'http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-3.html', 'http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-4.html','http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-5.html', 'http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-6.html', 'http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-7.html')
```

But that doesn't work.
Output:

```
"You can't pass both context and any of cafile, capath, and "
ValueError: You can't pass both context and any of cafile, capath, and cadefault
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get next pages' links by accessing the `code` tag with the `resultnav` class and iterating over `a` tags inside it:

```
pages_nav = soup.find('code', class_='resultnav');
pages_links = pages_nav.find_all('a')
# Access `href` attribute after that
```

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit more, explain why his code doesn't work and what yours do

Comment: @Whitefret Actually, he doesn't have any code that scrapes the next pages' links at the moment

Comment: look at the code, he tried openeing all url at the same time

Comment: This will only work if all the links are actually displayed on the first page. As it turns out they are in this case, but it could equally be `1,2,3,4.....19`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop with an index number?

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    connection = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-%i.html" % i0
    # process the file here
```

For a more generic solution which keeps going until the next page is not a valid link:

```
i = 1
while True:
    conn = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.theft-alerts.com/index-%i.html" % i0
    if conn.getcode != 200:  # perhaps retry a couple of times
        break
    # process the file here
    i += 1
```

The problem with your code is that you are trying to pass several links to `urllib2.urlopen` and that's not how it works. You need to pass each link and then process the response.

Here is the signature of `urlopen` which should explain the error you're seeing:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket.
            _GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, 
            cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
```

Comment: I think that he wants to have a generic solution -- maybe there will be more than 19 pages